# Core Data, Restkit and Local storage syncronization

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, restkit

My program uses Restkit with Coredata.

I need to persist 3 entities in the local storage so that I don't have to download a huge payload every time I need the data.

I also need the data to be refreshed when I want. The data should be refreshed in a way that only the changed objects will come through.

What is the best practice to do so in a system with CoreData and Restkit?

I see that Restkit used to have a RKSyncManager but not anymore..

Comment: What have you considered / researched? What have you tried? What problems have you thought of or seen?

Comment: Hi, I wasn't able to find out much about synchronization with Restkit and CoreData both in the system. I tried looking into Restkit's API docs but couldn't find anything substantial that gave me direction. 

One of the problem definitely is managing the whole set of data. My app will be built for Offline support in the future, but right now, I just want to store 3 entities and sync them at different events in the application like app load, login etc. 

Another problem is soft-deleting of objects but that isn't really very big concern at the moment..

Comment: How about searching SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737308/ios-restkit-sync-data-with-coredata or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831580/backup-core-data-with-restkit-0-20

Comment: Thanks, I had already viewed those questions but they don't really help my cause. I am open to modifications on the server side but I need to know the best way to do it before I tread on a path. Another thing that's different here is that I only need to store a certain number of object and sync them. Thanks.

Comment: So you have considered a data-stamp solution and passing the date stamps with requests and responses?

Comment: Right now, yes. It's more on the lines of getting the objects once, store them and make another table entry with the time of last update. The next time, send the server with the date and get changed objects and update the "updated date" entry in the separate table that tracks it. 

I am new to Restkit and don't have a ton of experience on CoreData either. So an approach and a brief way to handle stuff in detail is what I am looking for. Stuff like managing "Change" objects and implementation detail etc..

Comment: There is no standard approach. What you describe sounds ok. I would usually be tempted to give each object a last update date rather than to use a separate object (not table, this isn't SQLite directly...). Whenever you make a request include the last update date for that object (or if you send / receive a list of objects include the dates for each).